How big, in terms of say 32bit numbers, are the TYPICAL calculations performed by FLUX.1-* and StableDiffusion when making images?
I have NO GPU, and I rely only on my CPUs, namely 2x XEONS (WITHOUT AVX, AVX2, AVX-512, F16C) and lots of RAM so I'm curious;

*How big are the ACTUAL AVERAGE matrices, not all 60GB of .safetensors I'm assuming, it is REALLY dealing with in its waves of image processes and noise generation?

I'm assuming at the root of it is GEMM calculations but how big are the REAL matrices it's jiggling with and the length of each row and column it would be throwing at any AVX* instruction to multiply and/or add?


BTW even with my obsolete system I get one 1024x512 every 10 mins or so.
I don't use a GUI either so I save lots of resources there too.
FYI everything runs on a python script on the CLI and I operate it via my laptop using SSH using PUtty.
GUIs and GPUs are overrated IMHO.
Are most of the calculations based simply on the IMAGE SIZE, say 1024x512 which I am using as the benchmark for my system?
So some means, any means, to handle 1024x512 matrices quickly, say about several colour layers (RGB) of 524288 32bit floats is gonna be handy, right?

Diffusion models are, fundamentally, just neural networks. The networks are defined as layers which just accept input data and perform some operation with some existing data (the model weights). Each weight is a 32-bit number (or 16 bit, if you're loading a model which was baked in 16 bit). To that extent, each of those numbers in the safetensors file is "used" during inference (because each weight is used in an operation invoked by a layer of the model), but the actual number and size of the matrix operations is defined by the model architecture, not the raw number of weights.
You can look at the model architecture for a given model to see what each of the matrix sizes of each layer are. These will vary widely per model, depending on its model architecture.
For SD1.5, for example:
model_id = "runwayml/stable-diffusion-v1-5"
from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline
pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(model_id)
print(pipe.unet)

This will give you a very large output:
UNet2DConditionModel(
  (conv_in): Conv2d(4, 320, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
  (time_proj): Timesteps()
  (time_embedding): TimestepEmbedding(
    (linear_1): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=320, out_features=1280, bias=True)
    (act): SiLU()
    (linear_2): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=1280, bias=True)
  )
  (down_blocks): ModuleList(
    (0): CrossAttnDownBlock2D(
      (attentions): ModuleList(
        (0-1): 2 x Transformer2DModel(
          (norm): GroupNorm(32, 320, eps=1e-06, affine=True)
          (proj_in): LoRACompatibleConv(320, 320, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
          (transformer_blocks): ModuleList(
            (0): BasicTransformerBlock(
              (norm1): LayerNorm((320,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (attn1): Attention(
                (to_q): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=320, out_features=320, bias=False)
                (to_k): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=320, out_features=320, bias=False)
                (to_v): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=320, out_features=320, bias=False)
                (to_out): ModuleList(
                  (0): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=320, out_features=320, bias=True)
                  (1): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
                )
              )
              (norm2): LayerNorm((320,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (attn2): Attention(
                (to_q): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=320, out_features=320, bias=False)
                (to_k): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=768, out_features=320, bias=False)
                (to_v): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=768, out_features=320, bias=False)
                (to_out): ModuleList(
                  (0): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=320, out_features=320, bias=True)
                  (1): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
                )
              )
              (norm3): LayerNorm((320,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (ff): FeedForward(
                (net): ModuleList(
                  (0): GEGLU(
                    (proj): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=320, out_features=2560, bias=True)
                  )
                  (1): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
                  (2): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=320, bias=True)
                )
              )
            )
          )
          (proj_out): LoRACompatibleConv(320, 320, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
        )
      )
      (resnets): ModuleList(
        (0-1): 2 x ResnetBlock2D(
          (norm1): GroupNorm(32, 320, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (conv1): LoRACompatibleConv(320, 320, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (time_emb_proj): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=320, bias=True)
          (norm2): GroupNorm(32, 320, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (conv2): LoRACompatibleConv(320, 320, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (nonlinearity): SiLU()
        )
      )
      (downsamplers): ModuleList(
        (0): Downsample2D(
          (conv): LoRACompatibleConv(320, 320, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1))
        )
      )
    )
    (1): CrossAttnDownBlock2D(
      (attentions): ModuleList(
        (0-1): 2 x Transformer2DModel(
          (norm): GroupNorm(32, 640, eps=1e-06, affine=True)
          (proj_in): LoRACompatibleConv(640, 640, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
          (transformer_blocks): ModuleList(
            (0): BasicTransformerBlock(
              (norm1): LayerNorm((640,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (attn1): Attention(
                (to_q): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=640, out_features=640, bias=False)
                (to_k): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=640, out_features=640, bias=False)
                (to_v): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=640, out_features=640, bias=False)
                (to_out): ModuleList(
                  (0): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=640, out_features=640, bias=True)
                  (1): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
                )
              )
              (norm2): LayerNorm((640,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (attn2): Attention(
                (to_q): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=640, out_features=640, bias=False)
                (to_k): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=768, out_features=640, bias=False)
                (to_v): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=768, out_features=640, bias=False)
                (to_out): ModuleList(
                  (0): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=640, out_features=640, bias=True)
                  (1): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
                )
              )
              (norm3): LayerNorm((640,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (ff): FeedForward(
                (net): ModuleList(
                  (0): GEGLU(
                    (proj): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=640, out_features=5120, bias=True)
                  )
                  (1): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
                  (2): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=2560, out_features=640, bias=True)
                )
              )
            )
          )
          (proj_out): LoRACompatibleConv(640, 640, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
        )
      )
      (resnets): ModuleList(
        (0): ResnetBlock2D(
          (norm1): GroupNorm(32, 320, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (conv1): LoRACompatibleConv(320, 640, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (time_emb_proj): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=640, bias=True)
          (norm2): GroupNorm(32, 640, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (conv2): LoRACompatibleConv(640, 640, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (nonlinearity): SiLU()
          (conv_shortcut): LoRACompatibleConv(320, 640, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
        )
        (1): ResnetBlock2D(
          (norm1): GroupNorm(32, 640, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (conv1): LoRACompatibleConv(640, 640, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (time_emb_proj): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=640, bias=True)
          (norm2): GroupNorm(32, 640, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (conv2): LoRACompatibleConv(640, 640, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (nonlinearity): SiLU()
        )
      )
      (downsamplers): ModuleList(
        (0): Downsample2D(
          (conv): LoRACompatibleConv(640, 640, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1))
        )
      )
    )
    (2): CrossAttnDownBlock2D(
      (attentions): ModuleList(
        (0-1): 2 x Transformer2DModel(
          (norm): GroupNorm(32, 1280, eps=1e-06, affine=True)
          (proj_in): LoRACompatibleConv(1280, 1280, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
          (transformer_blocks): ModuleList(
            (0): BasicTransformerBlock(
              (norm1): LayerNorm((1280,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (attn1): Attention(
                (to_q): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=1280, bias=False)
                (to_k): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=1280, bias=False)
                (to_v): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=1280, bias=False)
                (to_out): ModuleList(
                  (0): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=1280, bias=True)
                  (1): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
                )
              )
              (norm2): LayerNorm((1280,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (attn2): Attention(
                (to_q): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=1280, bias=False)
                (to_k): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=768, out_features=1280, bias=False)
                (to_v): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=768, out_features=1280, bias=False)
                (to_out): ModuleList(
                  (0): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=1280, bias=True)
                  (1): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
                )
              )
              (norm3): LayerNorm((1280,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (ff): FeedForward(
                (net): ModuleList(
                  (0): GEGLU(
                    (proj): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=10240, bias=True)
                  )
                  (1): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
                  (2): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=5120, out_features=1280, bias=True)
                )
              )
            )
          )
          (proj_out): LoRACompatibleConv(1280, 1280, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
        )
      )
      (resnets): ModuleList(
        (0): ResnetBlock2D(
          (norm1): GroupNorm(32, 640, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (conv1): LoRACompatibleConv(640, 1280, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (time_emb_proj): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=1280, bias=True)
          (norm2): GroupNorm(32, 1280, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (conv2): LoRACompatibleConv(1280, 1280, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (nonlinearity): SiLU()
          (conv_shortcut): LoRACompatibleConv(640, 1280, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
        )
        (1): ResnetBlock2D(
          (norm1): GroupNorm(32, 1280, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (conv1): LoRACompatibleConv(1280, 1280, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (time_emb_proj): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=1280, bias=True)
          (norm2): GroupNorm(32, 1280, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (conv2): LoRACompatibleConv(1280, 1280, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (nonlinearity): SiLU()
        )
      )
      (downsamplers): ModuleList(
        (0): Downsample2D(
          (conv): LoRACompatibleConv(1280, 1280, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1))
        )
      )
    )
    (3): DownBlock2D(
      (resnets): ModuleList(
        (0-1): 2 x ResnetBlock2D(
          (norm1): GroupNorm(32, 1280, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (conv1): LoRACompatibleConv(1280, 1280, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (time_emb_proj): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=1280, bias=True)
          (norm2): GroupNorm(32, 1280, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (conv2): LoRACompatibleConv(1280, 1280, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (nonlinearity): SiLU()
        )
      )
    )
  )
  (up_blocks): ModuleList(
    (0): UpBlock2D(
      (resnets): ModuleList(
        (0-2): 3 x ResnetBlock2D(
          (norm1): GroupNorm(32, 2560, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (conv1): LoRACompatibleConv(2560, 1280, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (time_emb_proj): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=1280, bias=True)
          (norm2): GroupNorm(32, 1280, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (conv2): LoRACompatibleConv(1280, 1280, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (nonlinearity): SiLU()
          (conv_shortcut): LoRACompatibleConv(2560, 1280, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
        )
      )
      (upsamplers): ModuleList(
        (0): Upsample2D(
          (conv): LoRACompatibleConv(1280, 1280, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        )
      )
    )
    (1): CrossAttnUpBlock2D(
      (attentions): ModuleList(
        (0-2): 3 x Transformer2DModel(
          (norm): GroupNorm(32, 1280, eps=1e-06, affine=True)
          (proj_in): LoRACompatibleConv(1280, 1280, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
          (transformer_blocks): ModuleList(
            (0): BasicTransformerBlock(
              (norm1): LayerNorm((1280,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (attn1): Attention(
                (to_q): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=1280, bias=False)
                (to_k): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=1280, bias=False)
                (to_v): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=1280, bias=False)
                (to_out): ModuleList(
                  (0): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=1280, bias=True)
                  (1): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
                )
              )
              (norm2): LayerNorm((1280,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (attn2): Attention(
                (to_q): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=1280, bias=False)
                (to_k): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=768, out_features=1280, bias=False)
                (to_v): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=768, out_features=1280, bias=False)
                (to_out): ModuleList(
                  (0): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=1280, bias=True)
                  (1): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
                )
              )
              (norm3): LayerNorm((1280,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (ff): FeedForward(
                (net): ModuleList(
                  (0): GEGLU(
                    (proj): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=10240, bias=True)
                  )
                  (1): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
                  (2): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=5120, out_features=1280, bias=True)
                )
              )
            )
          )
          (proj_out): LoRACompatibleConv(1280, 1280, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
        )
      )
      (resnets): ModuleList(
        (0-1): 2 x ResnetBlock2D(
          (norm1): GroupNorm(32, 2560, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (conv1): LoRACompatibleConv(2560, 1280, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (time_emb_proj): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=1280, bias=True)
          (norm2): GroupNorm(32, 1280, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (conv2): LoRACompatibleConv(1280, 1280, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (nonlinearity): SiLU()
          (conv_shortcut): LoRACompatibleConv(2560, 1280, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
        )
        (2): ResnetBlock2D(
          (norm1): GroupNorm(32, 1920, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (conv1): LoRACompatibleConv(1920, 1280, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (time_emb_proj): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=1280, bias=True)
          (norm2): GroupNorm(32, 1280, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (conv2): LoRACompatibleConv(1280, 1280, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (nonlinearity): SiLU()
          (conv_shortcut): LoRACompatibleConv(1920, 1280, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
        )
      )
      (upsamplers): ModuleList(
        (0): Upsample2D(
          (conv): LoRACompatibleConv(1280, 1280, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        )
      )
    )
    (2): CrossAttnUpBlock2D(
      (attentions): ModuleList(
        (0-2): 3 x Transformer2DModel(
          (norm): GroupNorm(32, 640, eps=1e-06, affine=True)
          (proj_in): LoRACompatibleConv(640, 640, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
          (transformer_blocks): ModuleList(
            (0): BasicTransformerBlock(
              (norm1): LayerNorm((640,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (attn1): Attention(
                (to_q): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=640, out_features=640, bias=False)
                (to_k): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=640, out_features=640, bias=False)
                (to_v): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=640, out_features=640, bias=False)
                (to_out): ModuleList(
                  (0): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=640, out_features=640, bias=True)
                  (1): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
                )
              )
              (norm2): LayerNorm((640,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (attn2): Attention(
                (to_q): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=640, out_features=640, bias=False)
                (to_k): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=768, out_features=640, bias=False)
                (to_v): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=768, out_features=640, bias=False)
                (to_out): ModuleList(
                  (0): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=640, out_features=640, bias=True)
                  (1): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
                )
              )
              (norm3): LayerNorm((640,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (ff): FeedForward(
                (net): ModuleList(
                  (0): GEGLU(
                    (proj): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=640, out_features=5120, bias=True)
                  )
                  (1): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
                  (2): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=2560, out_features=640, bias=True)
                )
              )
            )
          )
          (proj_out): LoRACompatibleConv(640, 640, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
        )
      )
      (resnets): ModuleList(
        (0): ResnetBlock2D(
          (norm1): GroupNorm(32, 1920, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (conv1): LoRACompatibleConv(1920, 640, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (time_emb_proj): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=640, bias=True)
          (norm2): GroupNorm(32, 640, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (conv2): LoRACompatibleConv(640, 640, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (nonlinearity): SiLU()
          (conv_shortcut): LoRACompatibleConv(1920, 640, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
        )
        (1): ResnetBlock2D(
          (norm1): GroupNorm(32, 1280, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (conv1): LoRACompatibleConv(1280, 640, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (time_emb_proj): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=640, bias=True)
          (norm2): GroupNorm(32, 640, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (conv2): LoRACompatibleConv(640, 640, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (nonlinearity): SiLU()
          (conv_shortcut): LoRACompatibleConv(1280, 640, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
        )
        (2): ResnetBlock2D(
          (norm1): GroupNorm(32, 960, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (conv1): LoRACompatibleConv(960, 640, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (time_emb_proj): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=640, bias=True)
          (norm2): GroupNorm(32, 640, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (conv2): LoRACompatibleConv(640, 640, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (nonlinearity): SiLU()
          (conv_shortcut): LoRACompatibleConv(960, 640, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
        )
      )
      (upsamplers): ModuleList(
        (0): Upsample2D(
          (conv): LoRACompatibleConv(640, 640, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        )
      )
    )
    (3): CrossAttnUpBlock2D(
      (attentions): ModuleList(
        (0-2): 3 x Transformer2DModel(
          (norm): GroupNorm(32, 320, eps=1e-06, affine=True)
          (proj_in): LoRACompatibleConv(320, 320, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
          (transformer_blocks): ModuleList(
            (0): BasicTransformerBlock(
              (norm1): LayerNorm((320,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (attn1): Attention(
                (to_q): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=320, out_features=320, bias=False)
                (to_k): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=320, out_features=320, bias=False)
                (to_v): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=320, out_features=320, bias=False)
                (to_out): ModuleList(
                  (0): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=320, out_features=320, bias=True)
                  (1): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
                )
              )
              (norm2): LayerNorm((320,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (attn2): Attention(
                (to_q): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=320, out_features=320, bias=False)
                (to_k): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=768, out_features=320, bias=False)
                (to_v): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=768, out_features=320, bias=False)
                (to_out): ModuleList(
                  (0): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=320, out_features=320, bias=True)
                  (1): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
                )
              )
              (norm3): LayerNorm((320,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (ff): FeedForward(
                (net): ModuleList(
                  (0): GEGLU(
                    (proj): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=320, out_features=2560, bias=True)
                  )
                  (1): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
                  (2): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=320, bias=True)
                )
              )
            )
          )
          (proj_out): LoRACompatibleConv(320, 320, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
        )
      )
      (resnets): ModuleList(
        (0): ResnetBlock2D(
          (norm1): GroupNorm(32, 960, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (conv1): LoRACompatibleConv(960, 320, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (time_emb_proj): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=320, bias=True)
          (norm2): GroupNorm(32, 320, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (conv2): LoRACompatibleConv(320, 320, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (nonlinearity): SiLU()
          (conv_shortcut): LoRACompatibleConv(960, 320, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
        )
        (1-2): 2 x ResnetBlock2D(
          (norm1): GroupNorm(32, 640, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (conv1): LoRACompatibleConv(640, 320, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (time_emb_proj): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=320, bias=True)
          (norm2): GroupNorm(32, 320, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (conv2): LoRACompatibleConv(320, 320, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (nonlinearity): SiLU()
          (conv_shortcut): LoRACompatibleConv(640, 320, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
        )
      )
    )
  )
  (mid_block): UNetMidBlock2DCrossAttn(
    (attentions): ModuleList(
      (0): Transformer2DModel(
        (norm): GroupNorm(32, 1280, eps=1e-06, affine=True)
        (proj_in): LoRACompatibleConv(1280, 1280, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
        (transformer_blocks): ModuleList(
          (0): BasicTransformerBlock(
            (norm1): LayerNorm((1280,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (attn1): Attention(
              (to_q): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=1280, bias=False)
              (to_k): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=1280, bias=False)
              (to_v): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=1280, bias=False)
              (to_out): ModuleList(
                (0): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=1280, bias=True)
                (1): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
              )
            )
            (norm2): LayerNorm((1280,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (attn2): Attention(
              (to_q): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=1280, bias=False)
              (to_k): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=768, out_features=1280, bias=False)
              (to_v): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=768, out_features=1280, bias=False)
              (to_out): ModuleList(
                (0): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=1280, bias=True)
                (1): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
              )
            )
            (norm3): LayerNorm((1280,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (ff): FeedForward(
              (net): ModuleList(
                (0): GEGLU(
                  (proj): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=10240, bias=True)
                )
                (1): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
                (2): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=5120, out_features=1280, bias=True)
              )
            )
          )
        )
        (proj_out): LoRACompatibleConv(1280, 1280, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
      )
    )
    (resnets): ModuleList(
      (0-1): 2 x ResnetBlock2D(
        (norm1): GroupNorm(32, 1280, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
        (conv1): LoRACompatibleConv(1280, 1280, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (time_emb_proj): LoRACompatibleLinear(in_features=1280, out_features=1280, bias=True)
        (norm2): GroupNorm(32, 1280, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
        (dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        (conv2): LoRACompatibleConv(1280, 1280, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        (nonlinearity): SiLU()
      )
    )
  )
  (conv_norm_out): GroupNorm(32, 320, eps=1e-05, affine=True)
  (conv_act): SiLU()
  (conv_out): Conv2d(320, 4, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
)

You'll notice that the leaf layers are generally either a) Linear, b) Conv2D, or c) activation layers. Each of those layers has a certain number of weights associated with it. For example, norm3 GEGLU projection uses an inner linear layer which is 1280x10240 (in_features x out_features)
You can compute the size of the operations of each of the layers with its features, parameters, and the operation type. A linear layer is going to be a matmul of in_features @ out_features.T (plus a bias, if given), while each conv2d layer is a bit more complex:

Where N is the batch size, C_in is the number of input channels, C_out is the number of output channels, and H and W are the height and width of each channel.
The unet is only one piece of the puzzle; there are also text encoders (which are used to convert text into conditioning for the unet), as well as the variational autoencoder ("VAE", or "first stage model"), which is used to take an input image (or noise field) and convert it into what's called a "latent space representation" of the input data. The unet conducts diffusion in latent space (which, for SD1.5, is 4 channels @ 1/8th the height and width of the desired output image), and then the VAE is used to decode the
diffused latent back into image space.
This is all multiplied by your batch size. When performing standard diffusion with classifier-free guidance (that's what the CFG value is), there are 2 batches per input, which are then used to further condition the image during each step of inference.
